# Is there any drivers compatible with the monitor mode and Ubuntu for Nexus Touch 4?

Tags: wireless, drivers, ubuntu-touch

I installed Ubuntu on my Nexus Touch 4 (mako) and I wondered if it will be possible to use the following aircrack-ng to audit networks as if I was on my laptop with aircrack-ng start over?
I already try to install Aircrack-ng above, it installs fine, **everything starts and works** (airmon-ng, airodump-ng, aireplay-ng, aircrack-ng) but the problem is that I can't put the **WiFi on my Nexus 4 in Monitor mode**. It shows me an error message like this:

```
ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device.
```

And just below this message, there is mark

```
Monitor mode enable on mon0.
```

When I type `sudo airmon-ng` to see my WiFi interfaces, there are two that appear: "wlan0 [phy0]" but also "p2p0 [phy0]". I try to put it into monitor mode also but the same error message appears. In the "Drivers" section there to mark the two WiFi interfaces "wcnss_wlan" and in the Chipset there "Unknown" for both WLAN Interfaces section. I'd love someone to help me on this :). I'm stuck not being able to put the WiFi card from my Nexus 4 in monitor mode.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed successfully aircrack ng on my Bq aquaris but the wifi interface is not compatible so you can install aircrack ng or reaver also but it does not work

PS to install it use sudo mount / -o remount,rw that mounts the filesystem as readwrite and it does not break your ota(i do it a lot of times and i have the last ubuntu build)